# Lambda inside lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Just for curiosity. Discovered Lambdas a few days ago. I was jus wondering if something like that can be done:

(Tried on the interpret but none of my tries seemed to work)

```
p = lambda x: (lambda x: x%2)/2
```

There's no explicit purpose. I just did'nt find a satisfactory answer. I may have misunderstood Lambdas.

Comment: Yes it can be done: Look at this... http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't actually *calling* the inner `lambda`:

```
p = lambda x: (lambda x: x%2)(x)/2
```

Note in Python 2 this example will always return `0` since the remainder from dividing by `2` will be either `0` or `1` and integer-dividing that result by `2` will result in a truncated `0`.

Comment: The example was just to ilustrate the idea. And missed the point about having to call both functions.

Comment: @JuanGallostra Ah alright, just thought it was worth mentioning otherwise someone else would. I presumed the example was abritrary anyway

Answer (score 13):

You can use an inner lambda to return another function, based on the outer parameters:

```
mul = lambda x: (lambda y: y * x)
times4 = mul(4)
print times4(2)
```

Comment: Hello Haskell, Python missed you

Answer (score 1):

`(lambda x: x%2)` is a *function*, and dividing a function by `2` doesn't make any sense. You probably want to call it and divide what the value it returned.