# How does lambda inside lambda function work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

When I try to print and see what each function does, I'm able to call only the `h` function.  All others return functions.

Also, can anybody tell me why this code prints 13 and what is happening?

```
two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y,y))`
one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x) + f(y))
h = one_to_two(two_to_one(lambda x, y: x*y))
print(h(3,2))
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful

Comment: yes, there are a lot of examples  there, but I still can't how can the lambda use itself (like a recursion) - as happening in the first two rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lambda inside lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857204/lambda-inside-lambda)

Comment: I read it. did not get an answer from that. thank you

Answer (score 4):

That was quite a mind bender!

So let's just break the logic bit by bit. We'll start from `h`, it is essentially

```
 h = lambda x, y : x*x + y*y
 h(3,2) # output is 13
```

Now, we'll be good programmers and look for repetition. `x*x` and `y*y` are essentially the same thing. Why not have a lambda that does that?

```
 a = lambda x: x*x
 h = lambda x,y: a(x) + a(y)
 h(3,2)
```

Good, but I want the caller to decide whether to do `x*x` or `x**x` or `x+x`. Everytime I do that I dont want to change `a`. So I instead pass a lambda to `a` with whatever operation I want to perform

```
# a is just a delegator now. It just calls the lambda that it is "initialized" with passing the values twice
a = lambda lambdaIAmPassing: (lambda someValue: lambdaIAmPassing(someValue, someValue))
# lets pass a multiplication lambda
mul_a = a(lambda x,y: x*y)
# lets pass a addition doing lambda
add_a = a(lambda x,y: x+y)
h = mul_a(3) + mul_a(2)
print h #output is 13
h = add_a(3) + add_a(2)
print h # output is 10
```

Is this clear? You would have realized now that `a` is in fact the lambda `two_to_one` in your question

Now the final step.Do you see any other repetition in the code? we are calling `mul_a` twice and `add_a` twice. So to avoid this we define a lambda that calls whatever function is passed to it twice - once per parameter - and adds up the values

```
# Lambda that adds up the result of the function call
lambda_adder = lambda f: (lambda value1, value2: f(value1) + f(value2))
"Initialize" this lambda with mul_a
h = lambda_adder(mul_a)
h(3,2) # output is 13
```

Hence we end up with the code in your question

Answer (score 2):

```
two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y,y))
```

This equals a function which calls a function `g`, passing it two variables, both `y`. In this case, `g` is

```
lambda x, y: x*y
```

because that is the argument passed to `two_to_one` on the third line (`h`'s assignment).

---

```
one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x) + f(y))
```

This equals a function which returns the sum of two calls to the function `f`, passing the values `x` and `y`. In this case, `f` is the `two_to_one` function.

---

Breaking it down:

```
first = lambda x, y: x*y
second = lambda y: first(y,y)
third = lambda x, y: second(x) + second(y)
```

simplifies to:

```
second = lambda y: y * y
third = lambda x, y: second(x) + second(y)
```

simplifies to:

```
third = lambda x, y: x * x + y * y
```

---

So, what the code is doing is returning the sum of the squares of the arguments. In this case, they are 3 and 2.

[image: 3 * 3 + 2 * 2 = 13]

[image: 9 + 4 = 13]

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be relatively easy to follow.

```
two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y,y))
```

`two_to_one` is a function, with an input of a function (`g`: a function with an input of two parameters (as seen in `g(y,y)`), and output of a function (with 1 input `y`, and output of `g(y,y)`). Meaning it is a function of functions. So when giving `two_to_one` a two parameter function `g`, you get back a function, that takes 1 number and outputs `g(y,y)`.
e.g:

```
two_to_one(lambda x,y:x+y)(3)
6
```

We gave `two_to_one` a function that gets two numbers and output their sum, `lambda x,y:x+y`, and we got back a function that takes 1 number and output its sum with itself `two_to_one(lambda x,y:x+y)`. So with an input of `3` it outputs `6`.

Second line is similiar:

```
one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x) + f(y))
```

Take a function `f` (of 1 parameter - due to `f(x)`), and give back a function, that gets two parameters (numbers probably) `x,y` and outputs `f(x) + f(y)`.

Now, for the 13 output - working from inner to outer:

```
h = one_to_two(two_to_one(lambda x, y: x*y))
```

`lambda x, y: x*y` two parameter input - output of multiplication. This is the input of `two_to_one` so (remember what was written earlier) `two_to_one(lambda x, y: x*y)` is a function that gets 1 number, and returns it squared. And finally, feeding this function to `one_to_two` gives a function that gets two numbers (those `x,y` frim before) and returns their sum of squares.

In total `h(3,2)` gives `3**2+2**2=13`.