# Python arranging strings in a list

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming language and recently I've just encountered this problem and I really want to know how to solve it

so here's the input:

```
list = ["Sam-11,Mark-10,Mike-14","Martha-12,Emma-9,Kyla-13"]
```

the output should be like this:

```
Mark-10, Emma-9
```

// Prints the names with the least age in the two strings inside the list including their age

Comment: try and find some tutorials on list manipulation. you'll probably find some useful list methods you can use to sort elements.

Comment: make some sort of attempt before asking for an answer

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for tips on asking good questions.

Comment: Off the point but I'm really confused about what this list is meant to represent. Would you prefer a dictionary for this instead of a list? A dictionary is basically a key:value pair where a key is linked to a value. So you can have "Mark" linked to the value of 10

Comment: The first string represents boys and their age then the second string represents girls and their age.

Comment: ok. First, you need to put the code you are using. after that, we can help you to figure out a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested lambda statements when sorting lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671990/nested-lambda-statements-when-sorting-lists)

Comment: a nested dictionary then could be key:boys with a value of a dictionary with all the boys then another key:girls with a value of a dictionary with all the girls. so many possibilites lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a straight forward solution :

```
print(", ".join( [ min(each_element.split(","),key = lambda x:int(x.split("-")[1])) for each_element in list_obj ] ))
```

you split each element on the comma and then find max of the resultant list based on the secondary parameter then you join it as you want.

Comment: That is not straight forward in the eyes of a new developer... baha

Comment: Also the answer is wrong. This prints `"Mike-14, Emma-9"` not "`Mark-10, Emma-9"`. This is because you are using `max` when you should be using `min` and you are doing a lexicographical sort instead of integer sort.

Comment: Thank you Pault, I didnt notice , that he had asked for a minimum, and yes, thank you for pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: Now it works, but I would not say it's straightforward- clearly you had trouble with it yourself. You could improve this answer with a more detailed explanation for beginners. Also that line is too long, IMO.

Comment: your code works thank you so much ... now I'm trying to figure out the logic behind it for the future sml