# python dictionary sorting value within a value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

The following works fine:

```
from operator import itemgetter
d = { "a":(4,15), "c":(3,2), "b":(12,6) }
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1)):
    print k, v
```

This returns:

```
c (3, 2)
a (4, 15)
b (12, 6)
```

But I would like to sort by second element of `v`: `[15, 2, 6]`

Get the impression for a `dict` this is not possible. True?

I looked around, but cannot seem to find... sorting by `v` means the order of items is important I see.

Comment: There's no built-in for this, but you are hardly limited to built-in functions for the `key` parameter: `key=lambda item: item[1][1]`

Comment: seems like an answer will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native function composition in Python.

But the 3rd party [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose) library does allow this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from toolz import compose

d = { "a":(4,15), "c":(3,2), "b":(12,6) }

for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=compose(itemgetter(1), itemgetter(1))):
    print(k, v)
```

---

Alaternatively, you can use an anonymous `lambda` function:

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]):
    print(k, v)
```

Related: [Nested lambda statements when sorting lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671990/nested-lambda-statements-when-sorting-lists)