# How to sort a python list of strings which contain a number in the end

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a python list which contains strings but the last part of each string has a number. I need to sort this list in a way that the numbers are ascending:

```
[u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.12', u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.4', u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.8', u'TC ELEVEN. Warning n.1', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.10', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.14', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.2', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.6', u'TC HOLA. Warning n.4', u'TC HOLA. Warning n.8', u'TC TWELVE. Warning n.1']
```

I have used the sorted() functions which sorts the names alphabetically but it doesn't take into consideration the number on the last part of each string.

Comment: Use the `key` parameter to the function `sorted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `sorted` with `key` argument and a custom `lambda` function.

Here we need to split by `.`, take the last item and convert to `int`.

```
lst = [u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.12', u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.4', u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.8', u'TC ELEVEN. Warning n.1', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.10', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.14', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.2', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.6', u'TC HOLA. Warning n.4', u'TC HOLA. Warning n.8', u'TC TWELVE. Warning n.1']

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]))

# ['TC ELEVEN. Warning n.1',
#  'TC TWELVE. Warning n.1',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.2',
#  'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.4',
#  'TC HOLA. Warning n.4',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.6',
#  'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.8',
#  'TC HOLA. Warning n.8',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.10',
#  'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.12',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.14']
```

---

If you need to sort first by the integer, then alphabetically by the initial part of the string:

```
def sorter_func(x):
    y = x.split('.')
    return int(y[-1]), y[0]

res = sorted(lst, key=sorter_func)

# ['TC ELEVEN. Warning n.1',
#  'TC TWELVE. Warning n.1',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.2',
#  'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.4',
#  'TC HOLA. Warning n.4',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.6',
#  'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.8',
#  'TC HOLA. Warning n.8',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.10',
#  'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.12',
#  'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.14']
```

Related: [Nested lambda statements when sorting lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671990/nested-lambda-statements-when-sorting-lists)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = re.compile('([0-9]+)$')

l = [u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.12', u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.4', u'TC DUMAZILE. Warning n.8', u'TC ELEVEN. Warning n.1', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.10', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.14', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.2', u'TC ELIAKIM. Warning n.6', u'TC HOLA. Warning n.4', u'TC HOLA. Warning n.8', u'TC TWELVE. Warning n.1']

print(sorted(l,key=lambda i: int(regex.search(i).groups()[0])))
```