# Combining methodcaller and attrgetter with sorted

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, functional-programming, nested

I want to get a list of PosixPath objects and have it sorted based on the corresponding file sizes. I am trying to to this using sorted function. The key that I want to use for sorting is `object.stat().st_size`, where object is an PosixPath object, `stat()` returns an `os.stat_result` object, and `st_size` is the size of the file corresponding to the PosixPath object. I know how to sort based on either an object method or an object attribute using `operator.methodcaller` or `operator.attrgetter`, but I can't figure out how to use an attribute of the object returned by `methodcaller`.

I tried the following and some variations but it does not work:

```
from operator import attrgetter, methodcaller
from pathlib import Path

sorted(Path('my_directory').glob('*.extension'), key=methodcaller('stat').st_size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not meant to be combined. You should use a lambda as key:

```
from pathlib import Path
sorted(Path('.').glob('*.py'), key=lambda p: p.stat().st_size)
```

Or, if you want to change the sort field dynamically:

```
key_field = 'st_mtime'
sorted(Path('.').glob('*.py'), 
       key=lambda p: attrgetter(key_field)(p.stat()))
```

And, well, if you really want to use `methodcaller` and `attrgetter`, you could do:

```
sorted(Path('.').glob('*.py'), key=lambda p: attrgetter('st_size')(methodcaller('stat')(p)))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) is not native in Python.

One readable way to apply your logic is to use the direct rather than functional route:

```
res = sorted(Path('.').glob('*.py'), key=lambda p: p.stat().st_size)
```

There are, however, 3rd party libraries that do offer this functionality, such as [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose):

```
from toolz import compose
from operator import attrgetter, methodcaller

get_size = compose(attrgetter('st_size'), methodcaller('stat'))

res = sorted(Path('.').glob('*.py'), key=get_size)
```

In my opinion, if you would like a functional solution, you should use or write a composition higher-order function, such as the above, to ensure your code is readable.

Related: [Nested lambda statements when sorting lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671990/nested-lambda-statements-when-sorting-lists)